# How to reset style in VBA after adding a hyperlink in word

Tags: vba

I am using code that I have adapted  from here https://wordribbon.tips.net/T000672_Making_Hyperlinks_from_Coded_Text.html  to automatically generate hyperlinks in word based on matched text.

I have an issue though,  I would like to preserve the original formatting (style) of the selection.  The key part of the code which I am trying to get to work is:

```
Dim my_hyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim curStyle As Object
...
... ' find the text I want to match now apply hyperlink 
With Selection
        curStyle = .Style
        Set my_hyperlink =ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=Selection.Range,_
        Address:="https://example.com",SubAddress:="")
        my_hyperlink.Range.Style = curStyle
End With
```

I am trying to store the current style in curStyle,  apply the hyper link and then reset the style.

I am getting the error though "object variable or with block variable not "

Is there some trick to store the style apply hyperlink and then restore the original style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer two options to do it

1. Modifying Hyperlink style (once)
2. Reset font style (after)

```vb
Sub OldStyleHyperlinkStyleChange()
    Dim my_hyperlink As Hyperlink
    '...
    '... ' find the text I want to match now apply hyperlink
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHyperlink).Font
        .ColorIndex = wdAuto
        .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    End With
    With Selection
        Set my_hyperlink = ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=.Range, _
        Address:="https://example.com", SubAddress:="")
    End With
End Sub

Sub OldStyleReset()
    Dim my_hyperlink As Hyperlink
    '...
    '... ' find the text I want to match now apply hyperlink
    With Selection
        Set my_hyperlink = ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=.Range, _
        Address:="https://example.com", SubAddress:="")
        my_hyperlink.Range.Font.Reset
    End With
End Sub
```